# NuGet Package restore IS enabled but I get an error saying it's not enabled

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package-restore

I have nuget package restore enabled in my solution. However, when I try to build the project, I get this error:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

I have tried deleting my NuGet.targets and NuGet.exe file and re-enabling nugget package restore. It recreates the files and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you [enable package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

Try and see if this helps:

in solution explorer, right click on the project name and select 'Enable Nudget package restore'

also remember to rebuild each of your projects

wait until it gets restored and run the project if it works fine

Comment: Deleting everything in the /packages directory before rebuilding everything did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow below mentioned steps:

Step 1:
Please enable Nuget Package Restore by right clicking on solution [as mentioned in below screenshot]

[image: Enable Nuget Package Restore]

Step 2: [Follow this if the issue / error is not resolved by following step 1]
Still if you face the issue, please open .csproj file in notepad and check for the package path which might look like

[image: Package Path]

So your solutions directory structure will be like:
\SolutionDirectory\

Package Directory
\SolutionDirectory\packages

Project Directory
\SolutionDirectory\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj

Please open this .csproj [in which you're getting error in notepad and search for packages path and update it to its relevant path.

For e.g. my .csproj contained, if .csproj file contains ....\packages then update that path with ..\packages

Comment: I have a strange behaviour with NuGet in VS here. 100% shure have seen "Managing NuGet Packages Restore for Solution..." and "Enable NuGet Packages Restore". And the restore option was gone once I opended "Manage..." - how will the restore option come back?

Comment: If Enable Nuget Package Restore option is not there then please click on Manage Nuget Packages and update all the nuget package and click ok. Or restart the solution without saving the solution file and check to see if Enable NuGet Package Restore option is there or not.

Comment: I comes back after restart of VS. No option to update NuGet-packages in manage, without random combination of things from Guilherme Melo's answer above..

Answer (score 1):

I had already done what the blog post recommends (through the options menu) and it still didn't build.

In the end I removed the Microsoft.Net.Http Nuget Package and Reinstalled it and that fixed it.