# Complaining about not having enabled package restore for Nuget, even though it is the case

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a solution, where one project keep giving me the issue:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.

The issue is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849611/nuget-package-restore-is-enabled-but-i-get-an-error-saying-its-not-enabled), where I have enabled package restore, but I keep getting the issue. I have tried to delete the .nuget folder, clean cache, delete packages, clean solution and rebuild, but nothing helps.

When doing the steps I just described, I can see that I get the packages downloaded to the packages folder, but apparently one project is still having issues. I can't seem to see any missing references in the project either.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 update 4 and Nuget is the latest version (2.8.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look in your project file (.csproj) using a text editor. My guess is that there is an MSBuild target being referenced from an old NuGet package which you are no longer using.

In the example below, taken from a project file , if a different version of Xamarin.Forms is installed, not 1.0.6188, you will see a similar error even if all the NuGet packages are restored. The message appears because the condition checks that the custom MSBuild targets file exists, if it is missing the error is displayed.

`<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.0.6188\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.0.6188\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
  </Target>`

Comment: Thank you, it was the bcl files which was needed, but I hadn't loaded the nuget packet for it. Thank you very much!